# MySQL UPDATE query partly updating with default values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running an update query (in MySQL 5.6) on 2 tables joined like the following:

```
UPDATE c_cache cc
JOIN p_cache pc USING (user_id, attribute_id, calculation_quarter)
JOIN batch_table bt USING (user_id, attribute_id, calculation_quarter, client_id, group_code, version_id)
    SET cc.epop = SUBSTRING(bt.result, 1, 1),
        cc.excl = SUBSTRING(bt.result, 2, 1),
        cc.num_result = SUBSTRING(bt.result, 3, 20),
        cc.status = 'FR',
        pc.epop = IF(bt.enrolled = 2, SUBSTRING(bt.result, 1, 1), 1),
        pc.excl = IF(bt.enrolled = 2, SUBSTRING(bt.result, 2, 1), 0),
        pc.num_result = IF(bt.enrolled = 2, SUBSTRING(bt.result, 3, 20), REPEAT('0', 20)),
        pc.status = IF(pc.status = 'FL2', 'S', 'FR');
```

The `p_cache` is being updated properly, but the 3 columns in the `c_cache` is being set to NULLs and `status` to 'S' (all default values of these columns).

The rows that are being missed out are usually contiguous (in chunks).

This query is within a loop in a stored procedure that runs till all 'S' (stale) status rows of `p_cache` are marked 'FR' (fresh), i.e. computed.
(All rows of `p_cache` are present in `c_cache` with a one-to-one correspondence).

The `batch_table` picks up rows in batches of 25000 rows per iteration, and gets updated with computed results in `result` column through some stored functions.

This whole stored proc. is called from a MySQL event. Multiple events run simultaneously (each for an exclusive set of attributes) to find stale rows in the `p_cache`, and update both cache tables with computed results in batches using queries similar to this one.

This anomalous behavior happens only on the `c_cache`, but only sometimes.

The schema definitions are:

```
CREATE TABLE c_cache (
    user_id INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    attribute_id INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    calculation_quarter DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
    version_id INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    epop TINYINT(1) DEFAULT NULL,
    excl TINYINT(1) DEFAULT NULL,
    num_result CHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    status ENUM('FR','S','FL1','FL2') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'S',
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, attribute_id, calculation_quarter, version_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE p_cache (
    user_id INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    attribute_id INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    calculation_quarter DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
    client_id INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    group_code CHAR(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    epop TINYINT(1) DEFAULT NULL,
    excl TINYINT(1) DEFAULT NULL,
    num_result CHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    status ENUM('FR','S','FL1','FL2','S1','S2') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'S',
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id,attribute_id,calculation_quarter,client_id,group_code),
    KEY date_status_id_index (calculation_quarter,status,attribute_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Can anyone kindly explain why this is happening and suggest a way to avoid this?
Thanks in advance.